# Is there any other alternatives for load command in DB2

Tags: db2

We daily receive 7 millions of records , we are going to append to the existing target table.The target table is partitioned based on date

We are using DB2 Load command  to load data from one DB2 table (stage)  to another DB2 table target

call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('LOAD FROM (SELECT * FROM stage_table )
OF CURSOR INSERT INTO target_table NONRECOVERABLE INDEXING MODE INCREMENTAL ALLOW READ ACCESS')

As per IBM documentation , ALLOW READ ACCESS is going to be deprecated suggested to use INGEST method instead of that

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=functionality-fp1-allow-read-access-parameter-load-command

Question:

1. How to use INGEST method to load data from DB2 to DB2 tables ?
2. what would be other alternatives to load millions of records with improved performance.

Comment: What's your db2 version and platform?

Comment: Do you add / remove partitions with the data?

Comment: DB2 (LUW) Version DB2 v11.5.7.0

Comment: We haven't removed any partitions yet , The table is partitioned by month and having index on Date (at the beginning of every year we use to 12 partitions to the table) to accommodate daily data